# Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am sending data from controller to view below is my code.

```
 $this->db->where("tbl_expenses.expense_type",$exp_type);
 $result = $this->db->get();
 $result['searched_data'] = $result->result(); (error occur in this line)

 $this->load->view('admin/filter_result_view',$result);
```

Thank to all for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the variable name as below:

```
$this->db->where("tbl_expenses.expense_type",$exp_type);
$result = $this->db->get();
$data['searched_data'] = $result->result();

$this->load->view('admin/filter_result_view',$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CodeIgniter Result as Object or Array. The `result();` method return database result as an object. You can use `result_array();` if you need the result set in form of array.

```
 $this->db->where("tbl_expenses.expense_type",$exp_type);
 $result = $this->db->get();
 $result_data['searched_data'] = $result->result_array(); 
 $this->load->view('admin/filter_result_view',$result_data);
```

Update the variable name `$result;` to `$result_data`